# Plugin to extract print layouts layer by layer

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer, atlas

I need a plugin that lets me extract all the layers i have active in the file one by one as a print layout.
So when i activate the plugin it automatically gives me png files of every layer separately

i tried finding a plugin like that but couldnt find any. Does anyone know about a plugin similar to what i describe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*note : QGIS 3.18 or above to get the variable @layer_ids.*

You can do an atlas that will change the layer activated and not change the extent of your map.

0. Finish to add every layer you may use in your project. Verify they have all a different name.
1. Create a new layer with no geometry named "atlas_table" without fields. Open the attribute table of this layer and create the same number of features as the number of layers you have.
2. Create a new virtual field named `layer_name` that will contain the layer name to be used for layout. Use the formula  `layer_property(array_get( @layer_ids,  $id - 1 ), 'name')`.
3. In the layout, go to atlas tab and generate atlas based on the layer you just created as coverage layer. Activate the atlas preview.
4. In the layout select your map and go to properties and activate `Lock layers` and click on the button in the right then edit. You will have an expression windows put this formula `"layer_name"`.

After this, when you change atlas page, you will get your layer one by one. You can use the atlas export to get one PDF or several PNG.

You can create virtual field that will contain other information about every layer you can then use it in your layout.

Comment: thank you so much man. im going to try to make it into a plugin now