# QGIS print composer: Extract segments of layer name to text box

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm attempting to produce a series of maps in QGIS, each showing a different layer overlaid over the same region, each with an associated different title and legend to match each layer.
I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to extract the name of each map based on the specific layer shown.

For example, one layer is named `Opt1_00010Y_Critical_h_Max`, and I want to be able to extract a text box to the print layout that will draw out the `Opt1`, `00010Y` and `h_Max` elements to create a map label saying `Option 1, 10 Year, Flood Depth`. And then to be able to set up a function that will do this for each map automatically.

Comment: I would suggest that doing themes and using the theme name would be the best option. It could be done in theory with pygis, but with expressions only you lack a way to exfiltrate what you want from the map to something else. As the map has function to enumerate layers and to validate their state (is_layer_visible).

Answer (score 1):

There is two part in your project : create atlas that create one map for each of your layer, then adapt the text to match the needs you have.

For the first part there is a solution explained here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/395333/145110

For the second part, you have to create an expression to extract what you want to show and add it in your atlas table to make it work. In your example you have to add a field `Option_number`, `number of year`, `Label`.

The fields could be virtual field :

- For `Option_number` the expression could be `to_int(substr("layer_name", 3),1))`
- For `number of year` the expression could be `to_int(substr("layer_name", 6),5))`
- For `Label` the expression could be `substr("layer_name", 13)`

Then you can add a text zone in your layout to show your complete text.

```
 'Option '|| "Option_number"  || ', '  ||  "number of year" || ' Year, '  ||  "Label"
```

Comment: Using themes would be more efficient than handling separate maps for each as you'll have to toggle layers for each export.

Comment: Depend how many maps you have. For 3-4 maps, themes are easier… but I have the case to create 64 maps, and themes are way to long to create!

Comment: @Alrl no need to toggle maps layer for each export. It is explained in the first part (just click on the link).

Comment: @CorentinLemaitre right I see, though I would suggest that instead of having a static string hidden in an expression, it could be simpler to store them as attributes in the atlas, maybe even doable as a virtual layer. But that's a good approach.

Comment: You are right. I will add an edit to get it as a virtual field, but I really don't know how to do. If you know how to do then you can add your own answer.

Comment: I have discover @layer_ids variable and update my first answer linked. Thank for the feedback.